# Warning occurs when using nest

Tags: r, tidyr

```
tbl = tibble(a = c(1,2), b = c(3,4))
tbl2 = tibble(id = 1, t = nest(tbl) %>% flatten())
```

As above codes, I can put `tbl` as one element into `tbl2`, but

the warning message shows

> ```
> `...` must not be empty for ungrouped data frames.
> Did you want `data = everything()`?Warning message:
> ```

could you tell me how to do to omit the warning message?

Comment: `tibble(id = 1, t = list(tbl))`?

Answer (score 1):

In order to get the solution proposed by @Sotos with the hint from the warning, use the (apparently undocumented) option of the `nest` command, as follows:

```
tbl2 = tibble(id = 1, t = nest(tbl, data=everything()) %>% flatten())
```

It may be worthwhile noting (slightly off-topic) that this option also exists for the `unnest` command.